# APEX Trigger when a textfield gets updated

Tags: apex

I am trying to create a trigger in APEX, when an custom **textfield** of an custom sObject gets updated with products (means, when new products get insert or existing one get deleted).

How can I compare in APEX the Trigger.Old values with the Trigger?  New values of this field in order to start the Trigger.

It would look something like this:

```
Trigger NameOfTrigger on CustomSObject__c (after update){

/*there is already an existing list of products that get insert into the custom textfield (probably as Strings)
*/

List <String> textList = new List <String> (); 

/*PseudoCode: if the textfield got updated/has changed, copy from every entry of this textfield (entry = product name as a string) and copy fieldX into another sObject
*/

if(CustomSObject.field(OldValues) != CustomSObject.field(NewValues)){
for (String product : textList){
   //Trigger e.g. copy the values of a certain field of p and paste them in another sObject
}
```

Could somebody help me with the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize inbuilt **`Trigger.new`** and **`Trigger.old`** to get the latest and old values of any record. These lists can be used to achieve what you're looking for.

Sample example would be:

```
Trigger NameOfTrigger on CustomSObject__c (after update){

    for(CustomSObject__c customObject : Trigger.new) {

        // get old record
        CustomSObject__c oldCustomObject = Trigger.oldMap.get(customObject.Id);

        // compare old and new values of a particular field
        if(customObject.fieldName != oldCustomObject.fieldName){
            //Trigger e.g. copy the values of a certain field of p and paste them in another sObject
        }

    }

}
```

See documentation of [`Trigger.new & Trigger.old`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm)